Forwarding X11 desktop from a Debian RISC-V board to my Manjaro x64 machine
I have a Milk-V Duo S running an image of Debian specifically designed to run on the Sophgo SG2000 chip, made by Fishwaldo. I'm able to ssh -X into it via my Manjaro machine (which uses KDE Plasma) and was able to get the board to display basic apps like xcalc, xclock, and xeyes.
From there I tried installing mwm and launching it to see if I could forward an entire graphical desktop, but got the error
a window manager is already running on screen 0

Which I presume is the KDE Plasma desktop running on my main monitor.
That begs the question, how do I get around this? Do I need to turn off KDE Plasma and go directly to the command line or can I have it forwarded into another window of sorts?

This is actually something that was done frequently many years ago.  (case 3 here.)  There are a few possible techniques.

Run no window manager when you start X locally, then SSH to the remote host and run your window manager there.

As a special case, you could configure your window manager to be a script that does the SSH and runs the remote window manager.  You would need to ensure that your SSH doesn't need terminal interaction.


Run something like Xnest or Xephyr, don't provide it a startup on it's own, and send your remote window manager to it.

Use a display manager like xdm that is capable of using the classic remote management facilities (XDMCP), running this on both machines.  Tell the local machine to contact the remote display manager for login.  Note that this will probably require disabling the modern "bind only to localhost" and "disable TCP" options in the X server.


Alternatively, you could run a remote standalone VNC server.

Tried installing xdm on the board. Now I have another issue when trying to systemctl start xdm.service:
xdm.service - X-Window Display Manager      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/xdm.service; static)      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-06-12 07:11:50 UTC; 11s ago  Invocation: 0cfb4803f29d4c36afd04636ddaf55ae     Process: 557 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/bin/xdm" ] (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE). Not sure what to do here.

Well, I think that may be trying to tell you that xdm is not your default display manager.  (This should NOT prevent it running, especially on modern machines that can run multiple X servers.)  You will probably also need to configure xdm  (in /etc/X11/xdm/*), especially as a recent configuration will be set to be "secure" and not allow remote management.  I'm afraid I don't know details, but the documentation should be extensive.

You could try (per documentation in the init script): HEED_DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER=false /etc/init.d/xdm start

Tried that. I'm still getting the exact same error. Even after changing the HEED_DEFAULT_DISPLAY_MANAGER=false in the /etc/init.d/xdm file, and running the above command manually.

Well, you can always just run /usr/bin/xdm directly.

Tried that. Trying to connect via Xephyr -query 10.42.0.1 -screen 1280x1024 -br -reset -terminate :1 results in a black window as well as two _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed errors.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
